# Sextante Plugin error in QGis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sextante-qgis-plugin

I am an user of QGis 1.9.0. When I go to Fetch plugin option Sextante plugin is broken seems what is the problem?Even I agin downloaded the plugin in Qgis official resportary but it displays me the like below:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running a very old version of 1.9 I would suggest updating.

SEXTANTE is now built into QGIS and called **processing** now.

Comment: how to UPDATE please can u help me?

Comment: Use OSGeo4W and select qgis-dev in Advanced.

Comment: where to do this?in qgis environment or anywhere else?

Comment: http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/